# Tool for versioning parent and child

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, nexus3

I have the next uses cases:

Project parent v1.9

Child project 1 v1.3 (in .net)

Child project 2 v1.6 (in c++)

All child projects are in a repository in bitbucket.

I need to find a tool where I can administrate these use cases.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep those exact version in sync, inside a same repository, you could use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

First, create a branch at P v1.9.
You would then [`git submodule add CP1`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt) (Child Project 1) to P (Parent), and `git submodule add CP2` to P

That would add a folder `CP1` and `CP2` to `P`.
You can go in each subfolder, and `git restore` the exact version you want to have associated with P.